# Using hash to encode a PIN and save it to a database? PYTHON3

Tags: python-3.x, hash, sqlite

I'm currently getting my head around the hash feature in Python to encode with an algorithm a PIN number. After I have the user set their PIN number, I set it to the variable 'actualPIN'. My code is as follows below:

```
def returnCard(name, ID, rollingBalance, actualPIN):
    PIN = hashlib.sha256()
    PIN.update(b"actualPIN")
    data = (rollingBalance, actualPIN, ID)
    print(rollingBalance)
    with sqlite3.connect("ATM.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = 'update Atm set Balance=?, PIN=? where CustomerID=?'
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        db.commit()
    print("Thank you for using Norther Frock")
    print("Returning card...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Have a nice day")
    entryID()
```

Everything works, however the pin which the user enters is saved on the database. What I want to save to the database is the encoded password (obviously?). Could anyone explain how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the `actualPIN` variable to the database. Instead, you meant to write the digest:

```
data = (rollingBalance, PIN.digest(), ID)
# or data = (rollingBalance, PIN.hexdigest(), ID)
```

And you probably want to use `actualPIN` variable, not `"actualPIN"` string here:

```
PIN.update(repr(actualPIN).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I've tried that, but now when I use the PIN which was entered by the user to the program, it is given as invalid?

Comment: @D.Smith okay, if I understand you correctly, there is one more problem in your code - check out the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried that. Got this as a response: 

TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Comment: I just tried that myself after looking for the error code, and it still doesn't work! Thank you very much for your help by the way, it is greatly appreciated. I don't get an error code when I do that, but it just doesn't recognise the PIN I have put for the user. I also tried using a different hash algorithm i.e md5